# Reactjs not processed

Tags: reactjs, installation

I installed reactjs with the instructions of this website
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/react-on-windows
then I deleted all what was in the src folder and created a file in it.Next,I wrote the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactDOM } from "react";

const element = <h1>Hello</h1>;
console.log(element);
```

When I checked the react website there was nothing on the console. I think that Babel did not convert it into something that computer can understand.So, How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: You shouldn't delete all the files, just edit the `app.js` and add your code in it

Comment: What shall I edit in the app.js file?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-swartz-vrjyzd?file=/src/App.js